# ASP.NET Identity signout fails if inactive for longer than security stamp validation interval

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

My site uses ASP.Net MVC 5.2.2 and ASP.Net Identity 2.1.0. In CookieAuthenticationOptions I set the ExpireTimeSpan to 30 minutes and the security stamp validation interval is set to 2 minutes (so that users will be booted out within two minutes of a call to UserManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync.

The problem is that if users remain idle for longer than 2 minutes and then click on the Sign Out button, the site fails to log them off. After a bit of sleuthing, I found that in these cases the server returns a new application cookie (the cookie sent to the server was different than the one returned from it). What seems to be happening is that the owin code misses the call to AuthenticationManager.SignOut and goes ahead with the generation of a new application cookie, as it normally would have in cases where the old one is more than two minutes old.

Has anybody else encountered this issue? Any suggestions on how to diagnose and fix?

I am using VS 2013 Update 3, but this issue existed with previous versions of Identity.

UPDATE:

As an experiment, I created a brand new ASP.NET Web Application project with the VS 2013 Update 3 templates and noticed the exact same issue: I logged in and then waited for an amount of time equal to the security stamp validateInterval (by default, 30 minutes). After that I clicked the Log Off link and noticed that, just like in my own project, a) I was not logged out, and b) a new security stamp cookie was issued to me. I had to click the link a second time to be logged out. In fact, I didn't even need to sit idle for 30 minutes: I could keep making requests during that period and the click to the log out button would still fail, as long as it was the first request after the 30-minute interval expired.

This seems to be a bug in the OWIN identity code. Basically, if the first request after the validation interval is a signout request, it fails, because the code that validates and issues a new security stamp does not check if the user has logged out as part of the same request. Log out requests will fail, as long as they are part of a request that would cause the re-issuance of the security stamp -- i.e. the first request that is after validationInterval minutes since issuance of the previous security stamp.

I would appreciate it if somebody could confirm this behavior. You don't have to wait 30 minutes and do not have to create a new project. Just take an existing project that uses Identity, temporarily set the validation interval to something really short (30 seconds or a minute), log in, and ensure that the first request after the interval expires is a click on the Logout button. If this is a bug, you should notice that you are still logged in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also experienced the same issue.
I resolved the issue by changing my AuthenticationManager.SignOut to specify an authentication type as follows:

```
AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
```

Also, your OWIN components should be on version 3.0.0 (Which should be the case, since you're using Identity 2.1.0)

Comment: This is exactly what I found out a few months ago. It seems to be a bug in the identity components. I posted the fix (identical to this solution) on the Katana Codeplex site (https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/workitem/356), but forgot to update this forum. Accepting your answer.

Comment: I am glad you got it right!
It had me scratching my head a couple of months ago as well.
I had to do quite a bit of reading before a post on here led me to the default authentication types. I thought to give it a try and it worked! :P